# Cannot read sql tables into dataframe when I'm using 'where' clause

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I was using SQLAlchemy to read MySQL data into pandas dataframes. It used to work great. But from the past few days, I'm getting an error fetching the data whenever I'm using a where clause in the SQL statement. If I don't use the where clause, the query works great.

Below is the error I'm getting.

```
_mysql.connection.query(self, query)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1059, "Identifier name 'select M.uid,M.date from decuserdata M where M.date = '2019-01-10';' is too long") [SQL: "DESCRIBE `select M.uid,M.date from decuserdata M where M.date = '2019-01-10';`"] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Comment: Found solution on the link you've shared.. Thank you very much

Comment: Should I delete this question?

Comment: Here's some discussion about whether or not to delete duplicates: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265736/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-is-marked-as-a-duplicate